# How can I get an IList of entites and their child objects in Entity Framework efficiently?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, iqueryable

That is, I want to do this:

```
var lists = (from list in this.DB.Lists
             select new
             {
                 List = list,
                 Items = list.ListItems.ToList(),
             }).ToList();
```

But, obviously, the Entity Framework doesn't support the `ToList` extension method in the select clause.

What should I do?  Any other method I've tried ends up sending a ton of queries to the database when iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `Include` etension method?

```
var lists = (from list in this.DB.Lists.Include("ListItems")
             select list).ToList(); 

foreach(var item in lists)
{
   // there shouldn't be any DB calls here.
   var items = list.ListItems.ToList();
}
```

Comment: @John Gietzen, I know, it sucks... But you can use a lambda expression instead, see [this article](http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/) for details

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `ToList` on the part of the query that is translated to SQL, but you can do it locally, using `AsEnumerable`:

```
var lists = (from list in this.DB.Lists.AsEnumerable()
             select new
             {
                 List = list,
                 Items = list.ListItemsItems.ToList()
             }).ToList();
```